# Многострочный input

Tags: python-3.x

делаяю свой task manager, реализовал многострочный ввод таким образом:

```
while True:
    try:
        self.task = input('')
        self.join_task.append(self.task)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Как сделать многострочный ввод, что б я мог отредактировать ранее написанную строку. В моем примере я нажму enter и больше не смогу отредактировать отправленную строку.
Есть ли библиотеки или идеи как сделать ввод как в редакторе nano (linux).

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: нужно консольное решение, делаю для безинтерфейсного линукса